# How to fill Dictionary in ViewModel by values from TextBoxes in header of DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

We need to resolve problem below.
In View We have defined DataGrid and DataTemplate which contains TextBox. DataTemplate is used for HeaderTemplate of DataGrid columns. Columns for DataGrid are added dynamically from code (not in code behind of View).

My question is:

I would like to fill Dictionary in ViewModel. That Dictionary would be contain Keys = DataGridTextColumn.Header (column name) and Values = TextBox.Text and should by filled continually when text in TextBox is changed.
How to do it?

Here is my code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
xmlns:wpfToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderDataTemplate">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="tbName"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }

        private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid grid = (DataGrid)sender;
            ResourceDictionary resourecs = grid.Resources;
            grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Column_1", Width = 150, HeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)resourecs["HeaderDataTemplate"] });
            grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Column_2", Width = 150, HeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)resourecs["HeaderDataTemplate"] });
            grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "Column_N", Width = 150, HeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)resourecs["HeaderDataTemplate"] });
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public IDictionary<string, string> HeaderTextValues
        {
            //Here is Dictionary, which should by filled by Key = DataGridTextColumn.Header, Value = TextBox.Text
            get { return null; /*???? */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your VM should not contain *any* references to elements in the view.

Comment: This seems really fuzzy to me. Aside from the view references, I can't figure out what you're trying to do here. Why would you need that? Binding your Datagrid to a correct object would make life way easier for you

Comment: You may be looking at this the wrong way. In WPF, there are two layers: the data layer and the UI layer. Bindings are used to display data from the data layer in the UI layer. So the data (the dictionary values) should be stored in your ViewModel, while your UI layer (DataGrid) should pull its `DataGridTextColumn.Header` and `TextBox.Text` values from the data layer via Bindings. You shouldn't be attempting to push new data from the UI layer to the data layer.

Comment: It is for filtering data. I would like to write some expressions into TextBoxes and than filter data in DataGrid. I don't want to display content of dictionary in DataGrid. Count of columns in DataGird are changed in runtime so how to bind their TextBox content into dictionary?